# How to hide bound form data play framework

Tags: post, playframework-2.0

In play framework, what causes bound form data to be hidden on a POST request?

for example if a form has fields Name and Age with values:

```
name: John
age: 20
```

What causes the post request to show

```
localhost:9000/adduser
```

vs

```
localhost:9000/adduser?name=John&age=20
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is POST request itself.

This

```
localhost:9000/adduser?name=John&age=20
```

is a GET request.

It's good policy to keep actions that can modify data within POST requests and make server redirect to original page so that user won't see "do you want to resubmit form" alert.

It's also good style to keep actions that must be reproducible across machines within GET requests (such us search results so that one's able to copy'n'paste link and send it by email).

Comment: I understand its because of the POST. However, some of my POST requests end up showing the bound form data (i.e. after the POST request I get localhost:9000/adduser?name=John&age=20 in the address bar). I had an older play app which would hide the bound data so you would only see localhost:9000/adduser upon the POST reuqest.. Does this make sense?